# Replacing characters at specific locations

Tags: c#, regex, string

My input is a string that represent machine's execution time and date. The problem is that this string is formatted badly therefore I can't use `DateTime.Parse` to convert it to a `DateTime` object.

Input example:

> 2014-01-07-15.26.46.000452

I need to convert it to something I can work with (replacing the last '-' with a space and the first 2 '.' with a ':') like so:

> 2014-01-07 15:26:46.000452

I figured I should use regex to solve this because I need to replace characters at specific locations so `myString.Replace` won't do any good. Unfortunately, my knowledge of using regex is close to nothing and I couldn't find any examples to match my problem.


Can anyone help me solve this one out? (Also, I would like an explanation on how & why this  regex works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look very pretty, but does the job:

```
string yourString = "2014-01-07-15.26.46.000452";
string newString = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)", "$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6.$7");
```

It just cuts all the numerics apart from the gibberish around it and constructs the date you want to.

Answer (score 5):

You can parse it using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) by [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact( "2014-01-07-15.26.46.000452", 
                                   "yyyy-MM-dd-H.m.s.ffffff",
                                   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I prefer to stick with the regex but this is a nice solution too +1

Comment: @TzahMama: Maybe I am throwing in my own glasses, but this is the better solution.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It is probably better. On the other hand, I'm also trying to understand Regex. This solution is working good but I want to experiment with Regex therefore I favor it.